# Python Error using subprocess without shell=false and variable from an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, subprocess

I have the code snippet that works with shell=True which isn't secure and when i attempt to remove shell=True and include shell=False the program errors out

The code is below:

```
cmd = "git clone https://github.com/{} &"    
#define a worker function
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        subprocess.Popen(cmd.format(item))
        q.task_done()
```

I get the error below:

```
File "rapid.py", line 56, in worker
    subprocess.Popen(cmd.format(item))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git clone https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester.git &': 'git clone https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester.git &'
```

if i add shell = True to the subprocess line it runs just fine (see below) but then code factor flags it as insecure code. Any way to do this without shell = true?

```
cmd = "git clone https://github.com/{} &"    
#define a worker function
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        subprocess.Popen(cmd.format(item), shell = True)
        q.task_done()
```

Comment: *Substituting command components into a string and splitting it on spaces afterwards* is insecure, inherently. Even if you don't use a shell, if what's passed to you is instead of in `username/reponame` form contains, say, `username/reponame /etc/foobar`, you'll have `/etc/foobar` created if the code is run by a user with the relevant permissions. Which is to say -- the fix is to *stop substituting into strings which are then going to be parsed with whitespace as syntactically meaningful*. (With `shell=True` it's worse, because `$foo`, `$(foo)`, `>foo`, and many other things are *also* syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is being passed to `subprocess.Popen` as a string. This works when using `shell=True` because the shell can accept a command as a single string. But when `shell=False`, Popen expects the command as a list of arguments, the first one being the full path of the program to run. (This is assuming you're on a POSIX machine, not Windows.)

Essentially, the code says "Run a program called `git clone https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester.git` with no arguments" instead of "Run `git` with arguments `clone` and `https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester.git`".

The `&` should also be removed because that is a shell feature and with `shell=False` it would be passed to git as an argument it won't understand. You don't need it though, since the process will run in the background anyway.

Something like this should work:

```
subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/git", "clone", "https://github.com/{}".format(item)])
```

More info here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor